# Change int between 2 strings

Tags: python, file, python-re

I need to replace int between 2 strings or something like that.
ex:

```
["revolter"] = {
    ["name"] = "Revolter",
    aaaa = 195000, #This value (195000) needs to be tripled
    ["category"] = "sports",
    ["shop"] = "pdm",
},
["blade"] = {
    ["name"] = "Blade",
    aaaa = 19000,#This value (19000) needs to be tripled
    ["category"] = "muscle",
    ["shop"] = "pdm",
},
```

My code atm:

```
import re

f = open("fail.txt","r")
faili_sisu = f.read()
f.close()
new_value = #
faili_sisu = re.sub(r"(.*?aaaa = ).*?(,.*)", r"\1replaceble_int\2", faili_sisu)
faili_sisu = faili_sisu.replace("replaceble_int", str(new_value))

f = open("fail.txt", "w")
f.write(faili_sisu)
f.close()
```

I would like to know how can I get this int/str between "aaaa = " and "," to variable

Comment: What sort of file format is that? Wouldn't it be easier to just parse it, change the object or dict it maps to and then write it back?

Comment: What is `aaaa` in the regexp? Shouldn't that be `\["price"\]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replacement in `re.sub()` can be a function. It can convert the matched string to an integer and multiply it.

```
faili_sisu = re.sub(r'(?<=aaaa = )\d+', lambda m: str(3 * int(m.group(0))), faili_sisu)
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/qHMgZp)

Comment: umh, I dont understand quite well. I replaced my code with your line

Comment: I left out the space after `=`

Comment: Okay, it works when I use string that is inside the code, but I need it to write it into the file, because file is few thousand lines.